# comparar objetos y extraer los ítems que son iguales en javascript

Tags: javascript

Tengo estos objetos

```
var ciclosC4 = {0: 1.6, 1: 13.7, 2: 49, 3: 0.1, 4: 23, 5: -6.5, 6: -1.7, 7: 1.3, 8: -11.7, 9: Infinity}; 

var grupoS0 = {0: 0, 2: 0, 7: 0, undefined: 0};
```

Deseo comparar estos objetos por su ítem, es decir, si existen los ítems de la variante grupoS0 en la variante ciclosC4 en ese caso debería poder extraerse estos ítems que serias  {0:1.6, 2: 49, 7: 1.3} para poder luego comparar el menor valor entre estos (7: 1.3) es de aclarar que todos los objetos están compuestos por enteros , decimales o undefined. si faltan datos de la pregunta por favor comentar gracias.

Comment: Te falto incluir el código que tienes y que está fallando

Comment: Disculpen, estoy aprendiendo y me estrelle con este caso, he buscado toda la información pero no he encontrado nada parecido.

Comment: Si no sabes por donde comenzar, te recomiendo leer acerca de [Object.keys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys), es un buen punto de partida.

Comment: buscando información

Comment: @carlosing es un camino largo, pero entretenido el mundo del desarrollo. Ánimo y no decaigas si no te funciona algo, para eso esta la comunidad, para guiar, enseñar y aprender!

Comment: Muchas gracias, se aprende solo con retos grandes, a veces con ayuditas pero lo importante es aprender, muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te comparto el código funcional que he realizado, para lo que especifícas. En el código dejo los comentarios de los procesos a realizar.

De igual manera, te sugiero revisar las siguientes páginas para que puedas aprender un poco más sobre lo implementado en el código que dejo como respuesta.

[Object.keys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)

[Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty)

[Array.prototype.sort()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)

[Object.values()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values)

```js
var ciclosC4 = {
  0: 1.6,
  1: 13.7,
  2: 49,
  3: 0.1,
  4: 23,
  5: -6.5,
  6: -1.7,
  7: 1.3,
  8: -11.7,
  9: Infinity
};

var grupoS0 = {
  0: 0,
  2: 0,
  7: 0,
  undefined: 0
};

// Obtenemos la lista de keys que contiene el JSON grupoS0
var keysGrupoS0 = Object.keys(grupoS0);
// Creamos e inicializamos la variable que contendrá las key del JSON grupoS0 con los valores del JSON ciclosC4
var result1 = {};

for (var keysGrupo of keysGrupoS0) {

  // filtramos que la key no sea undefined y que exista en el JSON ciclosC4
  if (keysGrupo && Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(ciclosC4, keysGrupo)) {
    result1[keysGrupo] = ciclosC4[keysGrupo];
  }
}

// Imprimimos el JSON que contiene la información que necesitamos
console.log('JSON resultante', result1);

// Obtenemos todos los valores almacenados en el JSON obtenido en el for
var valuesResult1 = Object.values(result1);

// Ordenamos los valores del arreglo del menor valor al mayor.
valuesResult1.sort();
console.log('Valor menor', valuesResult1[0]);
```

Espero te sirva, saludos.

Comment: Muy bien muchas gracias, muy efectivo, espero aprender mucho mas,

Comment: He actualizado la respuesta y te he compartido los enlaces donde puedes entender como funcionan las funciones implementadas para la solución propuesta

Comment: muchas, muchas, muchas, muchas GRACIAS

Comment: Vale, con gusto

Answer (score 0):

Una posibilidad es filtrar las propiedades de ambos objetos (`Object.keys`)  con `.filter` e `.includes` y luego con `.reduce` seleccionar el minimo valor, sería algo asi:

```js
const ciclosC4 = {0: 1.6, 1: 13.7, 2: 49, 3: 0.1, 4: 23, 5: -6.5, 6: -1.7, 7: 1.3, 8: -11.7, 9: Infinity}; 

const grupoS0 = {0: 0, 2: 0, 7: 0, undefined: 0};


const res = Object.keys(ciclosC4).
filter(e => Object.keys(grupoS0).includes(e)).
reduce((p, c) => ciclosC4[c] < p ? ciclosC4[c] : p, Infinity);

console.log(res);
```